Error during dpkg configure - ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
I have ubuntu 24.04 installed and I am running sudo dpkg --configure -a and I get the following error
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-47-generic
   ...fail

and in the make.log the first error I notice is
# cmd_gen_objtooldep /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_params.o
   { echo ; echo '/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_params.o: $(wildcard ./tools/objtool/objtool)' ; } >> /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/.evdi_params.o.cmd
# cmd_gen_symversions_c /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_params.o
  if nm /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_params.o 2>/dev/null | grep -q ' __export_symbol_'; then gcc-13 -E -D__GENKSYMS__ -Wp,-MMD,/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/.evdi_params.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -std=gnu11 -fshort-wchar -funsigned-char -fno-common -fno-PIE -fno-strict-aliasing -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fcf-protection=none -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -mindirect-branch-cs-prefix -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fpatchable-function-entry=16,16 -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -fstack-protector-strong -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -fno-stack-clash-protection -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -falign-functions=16 -fstrict-flex-arrays=3 -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Wall -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-format-security -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-frame-address -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-dangling-pointer -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wcast-function-type -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -Wenum-conversion -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-restrict -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-override-init -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -g -gdwarf-5 -Iinclude/drm  -fsanitize=bounds-strict -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"evdi_params"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"evdi"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_evdi /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_params.c | scripts/genksyms/genksyms   -r /dev/null >> /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/.evdi_params.o.cmd; fi
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_gem.c:24:
/var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/evdi_drm_drv.h:29:10: fatal error: drm/drm_legacy.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include <drm/drm_legacy.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

If I do not want to reinstall my OS, what are my options to fix this?
